# Is it possible to disable\bypass "Sessions Timeouts" per user on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows, group-policy, server-settings, window-server-2012

I know how to enable\disable it per user:

You need to configure the Computer Configuration's Remote Desktop Session Host policies:

1. Launch the Global Policy Editor with typing gpedit.msc from the
   command-line and hit Enter.
2. In the left panel, navigate to Computer
   Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components >
   Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Session Time
   Limits.
3. In the right panel, double-click the Set time limit for
   active but idle Remote Desktop Services sessions policy: in the
   modal window that will appear, activate it by switching the radio
   button from Not configured to Enabled, then set the desired amount
   of time in the drop-down list right below.

But what I am trying to do is find out if there is a setting to disable it por user or per user group?

At this point, I'll even accept tricks on how to bypass it. I've tried mouse movers, key presses, webpage reloads and it still knows I'm idle.

Comment: The same Session Time Limits exist under User Configuration. If you want to filter them per user or security group membership, you should set them under User Configuration and then configure Security Filtering for the GPO accordingly. Note that if these settings are configured under both Computer Configuration and User Configuration, the Computer Configuration settings take precedence.

Comment: For some reason, that doesn't work. I still get timed out.

Comment: That's the problem. I have to have it on the Computer Configuration. I was hoping user config would take precedence. Are there any tricks to making it think your not idle?

Comment: Why do you have to have it in Computer Configuration?